# Compile error "QImage with no type" in Qt4

Tags: qimage, qt3, qt4.7

How can I figure out how to solve this bug message?

I am trying to rewrite a Qt3 working code into Qt4 for converting IplImage to QImage and found the "right conversion types" however my code as below results in "*ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'QImage' with no type*" compile message.

```
  QImage* convertIplImageToQImage(...){
            ...
            QImage *qqImage;  
  if (this->data->nChannels == 1) {

        QVector<QRgb> myColorTable;
        for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++)
            myColorTable.push_back(qRgb(i, i, i));

        qqImage = new QImage(qImageBuffer, width, height,
    QImage::Format_Indexed8);  
  }  else {

        qqImage = new QImage(qImageBuffer, width, height,
  QImage::Format_RGB32);

    }

    return qqImage;

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Check that you added #include  to your cpp file.
I usually get this error if an include header is missing.

Comment: Thanks Elle for your suggestion, worked great, but now got other issues to resolve, Thanks again!